# Camel SQL Stored Procedure syntax format

Tags: apache-camel

I'm new to Camel SQL Stored Component. I'm using camel-sql-2.24.2 version. 
The procedure I'm trying to frame is as below :

```
.to("sql-stored:SAMPLE_PROCEDURE(OUT VARCHAR id1,OUT VARCHAR id2,INOUT VARCHAR {header.id3} id3,VARCHAR ${header.id4},VARCHAR ${header.id5})?dataSource=#dataSource")
```

I'm using all IN,OUT and INOUT parameters. With the above call, getting back the following error :

```
CamelExceptionCaught= org.apache.camel.component.sql.stored.template.ast.ParseRuntimeException: org.apache.camel.component.sql.stored.template.generated.ParseException: Encountered " " " "  "" at line 1, column 85.Was expecting one of: {<SIMPLE_EXP_TOKEN>  <PARAMETER_POS_TOKEN>   <PARAMETER_NAME> }
```

As per Camel Documentation, I believe the syntax is correct. But, I'm quite not sure where I'm missing.

What is the correct syntax format?

Comment: Look at what you have a position 85 in that sql string. Also the code above has a missing $ in the first header. And see the unit tests also as they may have more examples.

Comment: Hi Cluas, Thanks for your reply. Missing $ in the first header was a typo error. It comes with $. At the position 85, INOUT param Name "id3" comes in place. Examples of unit tests are given with SQL type of INTEGER. Does VARCHAR also accepted?

Comment: You have comma 2 times after id3. The parser thinks its parameter 4 and 5. You need to specify INOUT on those too etc.

Comment: Hi Claus, id4 and id5 are IN params in my query. But, after id3, you mean to say the two commas for id4 and id5?

Comment: Try without id4 and id5. And also try to put them around single quotes, eg `dddd, yyy, zzz` so its a literal string value and the comma problem would be resolved